# DataContractJsonSerializer: The token 'null' was expected but found 'new '

Tags: c#, uwp

Getting this error when I try to deserialize JSON into an object.

```
Additional information: 
There was an error deserializing the object of type uwpPlatenInformationScreen.Models.RootObject. The token 'null' was expected but found 'new '.
```

I can't find any solution, I have it set to UTF8 and I have a correct model for the JSON.

My RootObject is not at fault, so I do not know what to consider anymore.

Function:

```
public static async Task<RootObject> GetTodaysLunch(ObservableCollection<RootObject> menu )
{

    string jsonMessage = await GetJsonDataFromMashie();

    //deserialize json data into object
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (RootObject));
    var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonMessage));

    RootObject result = (RootObject) serializer.ReadObject(ms);

    return result;
}
```

JSON string (poorly formatted by the API..):

```
{
"Weeks": [{
    "MenuId": "af77367d-9159-459d-863a-a23b00b6c7f8",
    "MenuName": "Skolmatsedel",
    "WeekNumber": 4,
    "Days": [{
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1453676400000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Köttfärssås med pasta",
            "MealId": "d09c0ccc-d491-4007-8ba9-3a47c83550ac",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Medelhavsgryta med quinoa",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Rotfruktsgratäng med fetaostcremé och sautegrönsaker",
            "MealId": "664a1858-78b3-467c-8167-53eb511f9117",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }, {
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1453762800000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Pytt i panna med rödbetor",
            "MealId": "359d7926-aefa-4a8d-94ff-9be6f9cfa2f1",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Spenatpaj med citron och fetaost",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Pastasås med linser och ajvar relish",
            "MealId": "86aadba2-0708-45d9-a714-15a78f90187c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }, {
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1453849200000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Broccolisoppa med mjukt bröd och ost",
            "MealId": "099234ba-3ebb-460f-961e-3dbc02de2b8a",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Pastagratäng med blomkål och spenat",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Quinoabiff med kall sweetchilisås och rostad potatis",
            "MealId": "00fb02c0-d514-48bc-a671-4843e3071f72",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }, {
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1453935600000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Herrgårdskyckling med kokt potatis",
            "MealId": "c48509e1-8e2e-4757-ac05-9c6c6923e2aa",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Falafel med tzatziki och potatis",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Vegetarisk Bourguignon med kokt potatis",
            "MealId": "7000c838-d08b-4399-a587-36556b22af38",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }, {
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1454022000000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Stekt fisk med remouladsås och kokt potatis",
            "MealId": "2de9af75-8d17-41a2-b5b3-68af5fb18b85",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Milanesesoppa",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Gula ärtbiffar med ratatouille",
            "MealId": "8c42119c-730e-43fa-aae3-ead09c4be6dd",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "MenuId": "af77367d-9159-459d-863a-a23b00b6c7f8",
    "MenuName": "Skolmatsedel",
    "WeekNumber": 5,
    "Days": [{
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1454281200000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Ost- och skinksås med pasta",
            "MealId": "238e7d82-bf34-4561-ae09-2df00129077a",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Yambalaya m äpple & svamp",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Zucchini piccata med tomatsås och ris",
            "MealId": "1b2c6040-6c76-4828-9f19-b123e80666a3",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }, {
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1454367600000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Fisk under sprött täcke med kokt potatis",
            "MealId": "663c2b1e-5167-4e98-b608-3d6ef64ebe11",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Solskenslasagnette",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Hemgjorda potatisbullar med vetekornspilaff och kall sås ",
            "MealId": "fe168578-3745-4bbf-9835-ae8e97dabb8d",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }, {
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1454454000000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Wienerkorv med potatismos",
            "MealId": "b6995939-5949-4acc-ac8a-4e3458ad1586",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Kaneldoftande gryta  med bulgur",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Bakad aubergine med tomatsås och basmatiris",
            "MealId": "f4396f3b-ee2f-4b8f-b862-983087685fd6",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }, {
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1454540400000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Tomatsoppa med pasta",
            "MealId": "fbe9a8a7-06a4-4436-8898-2523b21e4926",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Dillpototto med bönor",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Vegetarisk lasagne",
            "MealId": "08a9ec84-257d-4665-9733-0c2b8067a62a",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }, {
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1454626800000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Grillburgare med kall sås och ugnsrostad potatis",
            "MealId": "97bd6558-9bc7-46b6-90eb-8efae9a06da4",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Orientalisk quorngryta med potatis",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Lins och havrebiffar med myntayoghurt och rostade rödbetor",
            "MealId": "1a77a1bc-72a3-4c09-9cd9-78be7ede14c2",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "MenuId": "af77367d-9159-459d-863a-a23b00b6c7f8",
    "MenuName": "Skolmatsedel",
    "WeekNumber": 6,
    "Days": [{
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1454886000000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Kyckling i currysås med ris",
            "MealId": "9c9fddea-511b-4259-afad-89e48fe6d97e",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Het böngryta med matkorn",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Spenat, fetaost och citronpaj",
            "MealId": "97d515dc-ec93-48f8-9753-300ee99adbc4",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }, {
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1454972400000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Stekt falukorv med stuvade makaroner",
            "MealId": "90da4b39-b0f6-4427-8b1c-45517544a713",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Ostsoppa med brödkrutonger",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Medelhavsgryta med quinoa",
            "MealId": "4dbf7477-0d1c-4302-b287-f53fd41d1691",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }, {
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1455058800000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Fiskgratäng med dragon och kokt potatis",
            "MealId": "9fc6e0c8-7d04-4c0b-bd22-27393f80f1dd",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Pastagratäng med fetaost och broccoli",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Falafel med vetekornspilaff och örtaioli",
            "MealId": "e6eb174b-675b-4d04-b077-a795f7bf536e",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }, {
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1455145200000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Morotsboll med klyftpotatis och tzatziki",
            "MealId": "34e7246a-28c6-4859-8387-3dd40c5bc3de",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Pytt med rotsaker",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Rotfruktsgratäng med fetaostcremé och sautegrönsaker",
            "MealId": "664a1858-78b3-467c-8167-53eb511f9117",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }, {
        "InfoText": null,
        "DayMenuDate": new Date(1455231600000),
        "DayMenus": [{
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 1",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Lasagne med pizzasallad",
            "MealId": "6fe7683b-18db-4c35-a3e3-045ef70bd15d",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "Alt 2",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Bakad potatis med örtkeso",
            "MealId": "450e739f-7b16-432c-967c-6f1a6ef4b63c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }, {
            "PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
            "HasExtendedInfo": false,
            "MealPictureURL": null,
            "MenuAlternativeName": "VegFsk",
            "DayMenuInfo": "",
            "DayMenuName": "Pastasås med linser och ajvar relish",
            "MealId": "86aadba2-0708-45d9-a714-15a78f90187c",
            "ShowDayNutrient": false,
            "ShowWeekNutrient": false,
            "ShowIngredients": false
        }]
    }]
}],
"PortionTypeId": "c00dae2e-5d47-4439-be9b-9bb1e703e555",
"CurrentWeek": 4,
"MenuPresInfoText": null,
"MenuId": ""
```

}

Comment: Please post the code for `RootObject`.

Comment: @Tim The RootObject is posted in the answer below.

Comment: This may sound odd but does this happen in both RELEASE and DEBUG build configurations?

Comment: @MattWhilden In RELEASE mode I can't even get it running...  I get the "Unable to debug .NET native compilation code." error (Running all latest updates on VS2015). This is really weird.

Comment: We have a bug in .NET Native if you have a space in your project name. Maybe that helps you get further? Seems like a bit of a mess. You can mail us as dotnetnative@microsoft.com for help with .NET Native stuff.

Comment: @MattWhilden I do not have a space in my project name... project name "uwpPlatenInformationScreen". It seems like something is wrong with the serializer type, because I tried doing a different json object and it worked perfectly...

Comment: @MattWhilden I think what is not good with the JSON is this JavaScriptSerializer uses the following format of Date() - Date(1335205592410). While DataContractJsonSerializer is using this format Date(335205592410-0500). And I do not know how to convert to the right one while parsing the JSON data from website.

Comment: Hmmm. Now you're a bit out of my expertise. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the following: "new Date(12345)" is not reconizable by Microsoft's JSON deserializer, however "/Date(12345)/" is!

By using Regex I was able to replace and fix my JSON string before making it into an object by using the following code:

```
private static string FixDataTimeJsonData(string jsonMessage)
    {
        string tempFixed = Regex.Replace(jsonMessage, @"new Date[(]", @"""\/Date(");
        tempFixed = Regex.Replace(tempFixed, @"d*([)])", @")\/""");

        return tempFixed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your RootObject should look like this as below.

```
public class DayMenu
{
    public string PortionTypeId { get; set; }
    public bool HasExtendedInfo { get; set; }
    public object MealPictureURL { get; set; }
    public string MenuAlternativeName { get; set; }
    public string DayMenuInfo { get; set; }
    public string DayMenuName { get; set; }
    public string MealId { get; set; }
    public bool ShowDayNutrient { get; set; }
    public bool ShowWeekNutrient { get; set; }
    public bool ShowIngredients { get; set; }
}

public class Day
{
    public object InfoText { get; set; }
    public object DayMenuDate { get; set; }
    public List<DayMenu> DayMenus { get; set; }
}

public class Week
{
    public string MenuId { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public int WeekNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Day> Days { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Week> Weeks { get; set; }
    public string PortionTypeId { get; set; }
    public int CurrentWeek { get; set; }
    public object MenuPresInfoText { get; set; }
    public string MenuId { get; set; }
}
```

This Object will be deserialized successfully. If you get such errors, you can always use this website http://json2csharp.com/ to verify your objects. the one stated there "Object" because of null values. You can change them to string probably or appropriate other types if you know the possible values but the DayMenuDate is better to be "Object" type in order to deserialize successfully.

Comment: My RootObject looks exactly like that but still getting the same error!... I used json2csharp too. My GetJson Method returns a valid Json string.. but still..